# Repopulate html:select at checkbox click

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a form where the values displayed in a html:select depend on whether a checkbox if checked or not. How can I automatically refresh the select at checkbox click?

```
<html:form>
     <html:checkbox property="directSale"/>
     <html:select>
          <c:if test="${form.directSale}">
             <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
             <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
          </c:if>
          <c:if test="${!form.directSale}">
             <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
             <option value="opt4">Opt4</option>
          </c:if>
     <html:select/>
</html:form>
```

Comment: Can jquery be used in the solution?

Comment: Write listener for checkbox and after clicking it do the ajax call and fetch select box values.

Comment: does http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp could help you ?

Comment: It does not, I need the options in the select to change when the checkbox is clicked.